# How to log only 5xx errors on uWSGI

Tags: uwsgi

I want to let uWSGI only logging server errors and avoid the normal requests logs, because the file grow very fast, and all the requests logging does NGINX very well for me.

How can I properly configurate my uwsgi.ini for that? The documentation is not very clear for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally the solution was quite simple:

```
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
log-5xx = true
disable-logging = true
```

According to the help:

-L|--disable-logging                   disable request logging

Comment: In my case, I also wanted 4xx errors, so I added `log-4xx = true`. Here's the reference: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html

Comment: I am getting an error BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking when there are simultaneous requests. Did not have this issue before.