# How to disable request logging in Django and uWSGI?

Tags: django, uwsgi

My uWSGI logs are full of entries like this for every request:

> localhost [pid: 4029|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {48 vars in 906
>   bytes} [Wed Mar 23 18:35:38 2016] GET / => generated 94847 bytes in
>   1137 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 224 bytes (1 switches on core
>   0)

I'm not sure if it's uWSGI spamming them or Django. How can I disable the request logging?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What does your `uwsgi.ini` look like? That's where you'd want to disable logging.

Set: `disable-logging=True`

Here's the docs:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#disable-logging

Comment: Is there a way to filter on severity, I only want to disable info for example not warnings and errors..

Comment: @markmnl yes, you would turn logging on and then configure the logger to log by severity. Here is a good blog on logging by severity and best practices: https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/

Comment: Yes I know how to log by severity, problem is uWSGI doesn't - it only has the option in your answer to turn logging on or off completely! I don't want uWSGI to log every GET request but I do want it to log errors - but uWSGI provides no way for me do that..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I think this is the answer that you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702117/1913888, the same works for `log-4xx`

Comment: logging is not warning

Comment: with this change its recommend to use the log-4xx and log-5xx parameters to re-enable uWSGI’s built-in logging for responses with HTTP status codes of 4xx or 5xx. 

disable-logging = true
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true

Answer (score 5):

Or from the console with:

```
uwsgi --disable-logging
```