# Disable uWSGI logging

Tags: uwsgi

Completely new to uWSGI (as of a few hours ago) and I've been tasked to disable logging. I found this is what I need to add to my ini file: `disable-logging=True`. In my ini file at /etc/uwsgi/vassals/data.ini, I have:

```
virtualenv = /opt/our-analytics/apis/env
chdir = /opt/our-analytics/apis/
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = wsgi_app
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

My question is, can I simply use nano to add this one-liner `disable-logging=True` to the  bottom of the ini file? Would/should I remove the entire `logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log` line at the same time?

Then run `sudo systemctl restart emperor.uwsgi.service`?

Thanks!

p.s. I already checked documentation that was shared via [How to disable request logging in Django and uWSGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186324/how-to-disable-request-logging-in-django-and-uwsgi), but:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

Add:

`disable-logging=True`

...to data.ini, then:

`sudo systemctl restart emperor.uwsgi.service`

cd to /var/log/uwsgi and:

`rm data.log`

then:

`sudo systemctl restart emperor.uwsgi.service`

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting a small application, with flask for example, and not using a .ini file you can also include the flag `--disable-logging` in the command.

For example: `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --wsgi-file flask_app.py --callable app --disable-logging`