# How to set uWSGI loglevel?

Tags: logging, uwsgi

I managed to setup uWSGI logging into a file by setting `logto = /path/to/logfile`. The problem is that logging every single request causes the log file to grow too fast. How can I increase the logging level so that only errors are logged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `disable-logging` option as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702117/1330068).

You might want to also ensure `log-4xx` and `log-5xx` are enabled so that you can still see errors.

More info in the [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=disable-logging#disable-logging).